# Passing environment object between non-view classes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, environmentobject

I understand that `EnvironmentObject` property wrapper can be used to pass around objects to views. I have a session object which I am passing around to my *views*. Now I have a requirement to pass this into one of my *model* classes (i.e., non-view). Ideally, this model (receiving the session object) is instantiated as a `StateObject`.

```
struct CreditDetailsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var session: Session
  @StateObject var transactionsModel = TransactionsModel(token: session.token)
```

The code above will not work (understandably) because:

```
cannot use instance member 'session' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Any suggestions on how I can pass in the session into `TransactionsModel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try initializing the StateObject in an `.onAppear()` prop to a child view, like this:

```
struct CreditDetailsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var session: Session
  @StateObject var transactionsModel: TransactionModel?
  
  var body: some View {
    SomeChildView()
      .onAppear(perform: {
        transactionModel = TransactionModel(token: session.token)
      })
  }
}
```

This way, the variable is initialized when the view renders on the screen. It doesn't matter much which child view you add the `onAppear` prop to, as long as it is rendered as soon as the parent does.

Comment: Thanks! In another situation I was able to pass in the token in the onAction part of button press. So I guess the approach Identified by you above as well as the button press are 2 examples of getting this to work.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps you :)

Comment: How would you pass a reference to the environment object itself rather than just to one of its properties (in this case the token property)? I have tried to do it, and I get a plethora of errors.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I've found to do this (because you cannot have an optional StateObject) is:

```
struct CreditDetailsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var session: Session
  @StateObject var localModel = LocalModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    SomeChildView()
      .onAppear {
        localModel.transactionModel = TransactionModel(token: session.token)
      }
  }

  class LocalModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published transactionModel: TransactionModel?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@[Finley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715650/4698501)'s answer leads to an optional property.
@[Jason Bobier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70224551/4698501)'s answer requires an additional class and still leads to an optional property.

The SwiftUI approach is to inject your `StateObject` as an `EnvironmentObject` which avoids the problems with the previous answers:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var session: Session
  var body: some View {
    CreditDetailsView()
      .environmentObject(TransactionsModel(token: session.token))
  }
}

struct CreditDetailsView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var session: Session
  @EnvironmentObject var transactionsModel: TransactionsModel
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is an incorrect answer. Please check out the chosen answer above.**

You can access `session` object in `init`. In this case, `transactionsModel` should be done to be already initialized in any ways.

```
@EnvironmentObject var session: Session
@StateObject var transactionsModel = TransitionalModel(token: "")

init() {
    let token = self.session.token
    _transactionsModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: TransitionalModel(token: token))
}
```

Although it's out of the question, I am not sure if it's good way to pass something between them who look like being in different levels in the level of View.

Comment: I haven't actually seen any code supplying init on a View. But to think of it there is nothing stopping you from doing it. thanks for pointing this out. I can just invoke a method on model and supply the token via init.

Comment: Regarding supplying something in `init`. it's common pattern as far as I know. When you need to pass some value to a view and wanna use it as an initial value of specific @State/@StateObject, it's usually used like that. That case usually uses a designated init in order to receive the value from outside though.

Comment: The environment is not available in a `View`'s `init` method. This will give you a fatal error that no ObservableObject of that type can be found.

Comment: Oh. didn't test it. sorry for incorrect answer. I will put a comment on top of the answer.